# SSH connection error, connecting to different OpenSSH versions

Tags: ssh, debian

I just recently installed installed debian 9 on my server. In the process I encountered a rather odd behaviour when connecting with SSH. Sometimes it works perfectly fine to connect to my server, other times not so.

Pretty much the only thing I've installed is openssh-server, apt-get install openssh-server, and it's running with default settings.

I noticed from the log in my SSH client, Bitvise 6.24 that the server responds with different versions upon connection. Sometimes it says **SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.8** and then I'm not able to connect. When it says **SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4p1 Debian-10** it works just fine. I'm pretty new to Debian and have no clue why it behaves like this. Is it possible that there are multiple version of openssh-server running on my machine? I've tried to troubleshoot but haven't gotten far. Is this something you guys have seen before or know how to fix?

```
21:11:41.304 Started a new SSH2 session.
21:11:41.314 Connecting to SSH2 server XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:22.
21:11:41.507 Connection established.
21:11:41.798 Server version: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.8  <-----
21:11:41.798 First key exchange started.
21:11:42.438 Received a new host key from the server. Algorithm: ............
21:11:44.331 First key exchange completed using ecdh-sha2/nistp521. ............
21:11:44.412 Attempting password authentication.
21:11:45.798 Authentication failed. Remaining authentication methods: 'password'.
21:11:57.650 Authentication aborted on user's request.
21:11:57.720 The SSH2 session has been terminated.
21:12:13.332 Started a new SSH2 session.
21:12:13.342 Connecting to SSH2 server XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:22.
21:12:13.407 Connection established.
21:12:13.472 Server version: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4p1 Debian-10  <-----
21:12:13.472 First key exchange started.
21:12:13.632 Received a new host key from the server. Algorithm: ............
21:12:15.380 First key exchange completed using ecdh-sha2/nistp521. ............
21:12:15.441 Attempting password authentication.
21:12:15.551 Authentication completed.
21:12:15.691 Terminal channel opened.
```

Comment: Quite weird... I do not see a way you could get two competing SSH servers onto a single server. Two questions: Are you connecting using IP address, or a dns hostname? What kind of network equipment is between that server and the Internet?

Comment: I'm connecting with IP, there's no equipment between the server and the internet.

Comment: Can you post the output of `netstat -avneepA inet` and `systemctl status sshd.service` ?